# ReentrentLock on this object or super object

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

While delving deep in Java concurrency I found an example of Reenterant locking mechanism in **Java Concurrency in practice**

```
public class Widget {
     public synchronized void doSomething() {
...
}
}
public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
   public synchronized void doSomething() {
       System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
       super.doSomething(); // which object is locked this or super
   }
}
```

while calling method `LoggingWidget.doSomething()` **LoggingWidget** object's lock is acquired by thread . This method also call `super.doSomething()` in method its body. Which object is locked while calling `super.doSomething()` , `Widget` or `LoggingWidget`?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @OldCumudgeon : This is not duplicate . I am aware with the situation which you provided in the link

Comment: You're confusing objects and classes. You're locking on a single object, which is an instance of *both* `Widget` and `LoggingWidget`.

Comment: @shmosel : I got your point but still did not get it completely